# Customers without orders

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get a customer list with orders quantity. Actually use query below to get customers with orders like:

```
+-------+----------------+
| JAMES | 2 orders total |
| PAUL  | 6 orders total |
+-------+----------------+
```

To do this I use this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mod_users    
INNER JOIN (SELECT order_user_id, count(*) as order_qty
            FROM mod_orders
            GROUP BY user_order_id) AS order_qty
  ON mod_users.user_id = order_qty.order_user_id;
```

Now, I'd like to get users without orders too:

```
+-------+----------------+
| JAMES | 2 orders total |
| PAUL  | 6 orders total |
| FRANK | 0 orders total |
+-------+----------------+
```

Can anyone help make query to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT mod_users.user_id, COALESCE(order_qty, 0) AS ordersCount
FROM mod_users    
LEFT JOIN (SELECT order_user_id, count(*) as order_qty
            FROM mod_orders
            GROUP BY user_order_id) AS order_qty
  ON mod_users.user_id = order_qty.order_user_id;
```

If `mod_orders` doesn't contain any records for a particular user, then `order_qty` will be `NULL` due to `LEFT JOIN` for this user. `COALESCE` converts this `NULL` value into `0`.

Comment: You said to use left join but then you didn't use it.

Comment: @DigitalChris Ooops, my bad, fixed it. Thanks for the remark.

Comment: @Giorgios, works perfectly. Thank you very much. HID.